# Converting @Effect to createEffect NGRX

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am converting an @Effect (which obviously is now deprecated), to a createEffect, however I am seeing some errors I was not expecting and can't understand why.

Previous effect:

```
  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  LoginSuccess: Observable<any> = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN),
    tap((user) => {
      localStorage.setItem('jwt', user.payload.token);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    })
  );
```

New Effect:

```
  loginSuccess$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN),
      tap((user) => {
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', user.payload.token);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      })
    ),
    { dispatch: false }
  });
```

The errors:

> Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'never'.

> Argument of type '() => { dispatch: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => EffectResult'.

In anyone can point out my obvious error, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the actual `actionCreator` returned from `createAction` to `ofType` ie:

```
export const successfulLoginAction = createAction('[User] Login Succeeded', props<{ token: string }>());
```

```
    return this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(successfulLoginAction),
      tap((action) => {
          localStorage.setItem('jwt', action.token);
      ...
```

If you want to use old style action classes, then you need to pass the action type to `ofType`:

```
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType<LoginSuccess>(AuthActions.SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN),
      tap((action) => {
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', action.payload.token);
      ...
  );
```

Comment: Hi - This is how I am setting up my actions: export class LoginSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = AuthActions.SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN;
  constructor(public payload: any) {}
} - How do I go about using the above method?

Comment: see updated answer above but I suggest you update your actions to use `createAction` as you have for your effects.

Comment: I appreciate that, I am still getting an issue of: Argument of type '() => { dispatch: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => EffectResult<Action>'. This is highlighted here: createEffect(() => {

Comment: You will have misplaced brackets near the end of the `createEffect` function. See (somewhat) working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-effects-example-be9nhk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Feffects.ts

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. One last last question, when login occurs, it currently returns new LoginSuccess(user); How can I call into my new action if exporting as a const?

Comment: I think you are asking how to return an action created with `createAction`? you can do `map(() => successfulLoginAction({token: 'abc' })`